# How to get keyboard shortcuts Gmail HTML version?

Tags: gmail, email, google-chrome

I want to be able to open emails in new tabs using Gmail and Chrome.
I have found that using the HTML version works well for this (see 
[1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35871/how-to-open-new-tabs-for-each-mail-gmail-yahoo-outlook-hotmail/35903#35903) 
[2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119995/gmail-how-to-open-emails-in-an-independent-new-tab)),
but now my keyboard shortcuts aren't working.

Is there a way to have both 'open emails in tabs' and keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: what kind of shortcuts you are after?

Comment: Basic ones, like `e` for archive etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's unfortunately not possible as it's stated on the **[help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049?hl=en)**

> When you're in Basic HTML view, you won't see some Gmail features, including:
>
> - ...
> - Keyboard shortcuts
> - ...

however, there are other ways how to have custom shortcuts. for example, you can create them with **[AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)**